# Making one div scroll in front of another?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been attempting to make one div scroll in front of another.

However, I've come a little stuck.

The #wrapper div, overlaps the #header div on load.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/QY6Dv/1/)

Also, when I transfer that to Sublime Text 2 it doesn't work at all – I can't even see the image.

Here's what I'm seeing in ST2.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-UK">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DivTest.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var header_w=$('#header').height();

$('#wrapper').css('margin-top',header_w+'px');

$(window).resize(function()
{
    header_w=$('#header').height();

    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top',header_w+'px');
});
</script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="header">
        <img src="http://davesizer.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/eva_jump.jpg" alt="Dog">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html,
body
{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
}
#header
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-size:100%;
}
#header img
{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:99;
}
#wrapper
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
}
#outer
{
    margin:30px auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    height:1500px;
    background-color:red;
}
#inner
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    top:20px
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var header_h = $('#header').height();
    $('#wrapper').css('margin-top', header_h + 'px');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var header = $('#header');
        var opac = Math.max(0, 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / header.height());
        header.css('opacity', opac);
    });
});
```

and [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/RP9sB/)

Comment: That removes the image completely. It should look like this on page load: http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/9MFDB/

Comment: Michael, you want it to look like a movie frame?

Comment: No, it should look like the Fiddle in my comment. And behave like: http://fearthegrizzly.com/ (as in the grey #wrapper div) overlaps the image on scroll